# userAgent conflict in IE 8+ versions crossrider extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, user-agent, crossrider

I am trying to get call a page on my server from crossrider extension.

i am getting the user Agent differently when i a checking my server logs.

I am validating some logic based on the UserAgents of the browser.

it is in the form like below in browser **User-Agent    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko**

Below you can see the Browser headers

[image: you can see IE User-Agent headers]

and my in my server Logs

[image: my server logs]

**server userAgent : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.2; rv:11.0) like Gecko**

Looking around whether i can override it from crossrider API or jquery.

I am using **appAPI.request.get** method to call my page.

I am having this issue only in IE versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user-agent string from HTTP header and the one which could be obtained via Java-Script differ since version 9 of Microsoft IE because of the so called feature tokens. Some background could be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

There is no workaround you either have to live with the different versions ore use strictly only on of both (eg logging the JS version to server log via AJAX ore something similar, depending on your exact purpose).

Comment: can't we over ride or send UserAgent using jquery

$.ajaxSetup({
      headers:{'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko'}
    })